# Spring jar not loading property file

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have created one client application which consumes restfull web service. It is MAVEN java project. I have defined all URL for web service in properties file. If I run this client separately it works fine and gives proper result. Now I have created jar of the same application and added in the build path of another web application. When i deploy web application it gives error `FileNotFoundException`. It is unable to read property file in jar.

```
    @Autowired
    private Environment props;

    public String getAllAccounts(){
        try {
            return restEasyClient.invokeService(props
                    .getProperty("GET_ALL_ACCOUNTS"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is a code that work as a separate java project but not as a jar in web application.

This is how I am reading properties file using spring:

```
<bean name="props" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:/client.properties</value>
            </list>
    </property>
 </bean>
```

Any help??

Comment: Could you try using System.getProperty("GET_ALL_ACCOUNTS");

Comment: Is the "client.properties" file in the JAR (or WAR) in the correct classpath location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a / after classpath: I think that the problem is because you are not reaching properly the location of your File, consider this documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-classpath-wildcards Also consider that classpath will look by itself inside of src/main/resources, src/test/resources, src/main/java and src/test/java.